# PHP Pass by reference error after using same var

Tags: php, reference

Take a look to this code, and help me to understand the result

```
$x = array('hello', 'beautiful', 'world');
$y = array('bye bye','world', 'harsh');

foreach ($x as $n => &$v) { }

$v = "DONT CHANGE!";

foreach ($y as $n => $v){ }

print_r($x);
die;
```

It prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => beautiful
    [2] => harsh
)
```

Why it changes the LAST element of the $x? it just dont follow any logic!

Comment: It is worth noting that there is zero benefit to using references in day to day code unless you understand all of the pitfalls and side-effects.

Comment: I was using with big arrays to use less memory usage. The solution I guess is to use unset after the foreach... to break the reference.

Comment: PHP variables are copy-on-write.  There is no memory benefit to using references in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this loop is executed:

```
foreach ($x as $n => &$v) { }
```

`$v` ends up as a reference to `$x[2]`. Whatever you assign to `$v` actually gets assigned `$x[2]`. So at each iteration of the second loop:

```
foreach ($y as $n => $v) { }
```

`$v` (or should I say `$x[2]`) becomes:

- `'bye bye'`
- `'world'`
- `'harsh'`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but shouldnt php remove the reference if using it in a foreach? I always like to use $v as my value and if i pass it as reference all my previous used arrays got broken.

Its the first time I notice this beacause im working in a script without OOP.

The only way to make it work is to call unset($v) directly after the first foreach

Comment: This is the expected behavior. See the last line of @inhan answer where he has mentioned a good practice in such situations.

Answer (score 4):

```
// ...
$v = "DONT CHANGE!";
unset($v);
// ...
```

because `$v` is still a reference, which later takes the last item in the last foreach loop.

**EDIT:** See [the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) where it reads (in a code block)

> `unset($value); // break the reference with the last element`

Comment: Thanks you so much for the link to the reference, there is a WARNING note also that clarifies this.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loops are not functions.An ampersand(&) at foreach does not work to preserve the values  like at functions.
So even if you have  $var in the  second foreach ()   do not expect it to be like a "ghost" out of the loop.

Comment: please avoid using abbreviations in sentences