# How does a reference in a for-each loop change an element of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

```
$arr=array('a'=>'first','b'=>'second','c'=>'third');
foreach($arr as &$a);
foreach($arr as $a);
print_r($arr);
```

The above code changes the last element of `$arr ['c'=>'second']`. How does it do that?

Comment: Please learn how to use a `foreach` loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: _always, always, always, always_ `unset()` references when you're done with them, _especially_ if you're going to 'recycle' the variable name. Put an `unset($a);` between the first & second `foreach`.

Comment: @MikeK: he know how to use them. This is perhaps a bit _extreme_ example of 'minimal code that illustrates' the problem, but it is that: perfectly valid, and shows the problem. I for one am grateful that the OP did not bother us with what he wants to do inside the loop(s), as that is not important for this issue.

Comment: @Nehal: I'd ignore the downvotes. It says more about limited knowledge of the the downvoters then your question.

Comment: It is a good question but I am sure it has been asked before.

Comment: Ah... there you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650898/php-pass-by-reference-error-after-using-same-var

Comment: Ah, thank you, closing as dupe.

Comment: sorry, i didn't know there was a same question, i didn't find it because the title was different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating references in the first loop. At the end of the loop `$a` is still a reference to the last value in the array:

```
$arr = ['a','b','c'];
foreach($arr as &$a);
debug_zval_dump($arr,$a);
```

---

```
array(3) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  &string(1) "c" refcount(2)
}
```

So, assigning something to $a will change that value:

```
//... previous code, and then:
$a = 'I am still a reference';
debug_zval_dump($arr);
```

---

```
array(3) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  &string(22) "I am still a reference" refcount(2)
}
```

... so, if you do a second foreach, this will happen: the last item in your array will take on the value of the first item, so its original value is lost, and all following items of the array. However, when it gets set to itself (the last one), its original value has already been lost, and it doesn't change anything, so the last value of the array will take on the value of the item before last:

```
foreach($arr as $a){
    debug_zval_dump($arr);
}
```

---

```
array(3) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  &string(1) "a" refcount(2)
}
array(3) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  &string(1) "b" refcount(2)
}
array(3) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  &string(1) "b" refcount(2)
}
```

In short: always do this when using references in a loop unless you have a *very* good reason not to:

```
foreach($array as &$a){
    // some logic
}
unset($a); // removes the reference, so you can't accidentally assign something to it and thereby mutate $array itself.
```